# Adding dynamic data to extjs store

Tags: extjs, store

I need to add a lots of records into an extjs data store dynamically by looping. But store.add takes normally much time. Is it possible to add these data togetherly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use store.[loadData()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData) or store.[loadRecords()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadRecords) methods:

```
 var mydata = [
     [1, 'John', 'Smith'],
     [2, 'Fred', 'Jones']
 ];
store.loadData(mydata, false);
```

Comment: But this takes also long time. While debugging, wwe can understand it.

Comment: This ia wide web application. Within it in one page I have a grid which contains several applicants and their details. When we click in a particular column of an applicant, a popup window will open. In this popup, I have another three grids which contains some other details of that applicant. But data can be inserted to each store corresponding to each grid only after clicking on the applicant applicant in the first grid. Adding data to stores take more time and so the opening of popup window is too slow. I cant do it anywhere else or I cant set it earlier. That is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

When adding or modifying big amount of data in ExtJS Store, I suggest you to disable all events by using method:

```
store.suspendEvents();
for(var i=0; i<9000, i++) {
    store.add({ ... });
}
store.resumeEvents();
```

And when your inserting finishes, enable events again. This can very much improve your performance.